# How to use second subscription return value in first's running subscription in sync in angular 6?

Tags: angular, api, http, observable

I am using angular 6 app. In my case I have a one situation, in which I have to call another API and take data and then pass to first API and then resume API.

For example, in `.ts` file:

```
logout(){
  this.apiService.POST({}, "logout").subscribe((response: any) => 
  {
      alert("Logout subscribed returns...");
  }
}
```

In **api.service.ts** file:

```
POST(param, apiName) {
     var URL = Config.POST_ENDPOINT_URL + apiName; // Make whole API string
    
     return this.http.post(URL, param, options)
       .map(data => {
             // Hear I have to call another HTTP API call 
             // if I got specific status code in data. 
             var apiRes: any = data;
            
             if(apiRes.code == 500){
                   // Hear I need to call another API call 
                   this.another()subscribe((anotherResponse) => {
                      console.log("anotherResponse :::" , anotherResponse);

                   // Now the main issue is come in picture. I need data form

                   // anotherRespose and pass in POST to continue API call. 

                   // In short , I need to again call POST function with new data. 
                   })
             }

       });
     
}


another(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(URL, obj, options)
      .map(data => {          
        alert("another data return...");
        return data;  // Need to pass this data
      })
}
```

In addition, when I call `logout()` it will return it's subscribed while `another()`  is running. So, I need to set my flow in a sync.

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: @Vikas I have already look in to this link. But it not works me. Well thanks for reply. :)

Comment: what's the issue you got when u tried the stated soln from the blog

Comment: It returns data while any second subscription is running. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
POST(param, apiName) {

 return new Observable<number>(observer => {

    var URL = Config.POST_ENDPOINT_URL + apiName; // Make whole API string

    this.http.post(URL, param, options)
        .subscribe(data => {
            // Hear I have to call another HTTP API call 
            // if I got specific status code in data. 
            var apiRes: any = data;

            if(apiRes.code == 500){
                // Hear I need to call another API call 
                this.another()subscribe((anotherResponse) => {
                    console.log("anotherResponse :::" , anotherResponse);

                    observer.next(anotherResponse);
                    observer.complete();
                })
            }

   });

 }

}
```

Comment: I have implement your code but I got some error. Error: Argument of type '(this: Observable<any>, observer: Subscriber<any>) => Observable<Object>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable<any>, subscriber: Subscriber<any>) => TeardownLogic'.
  Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.
    Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Unsubscribable'.
      Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type 'Observable<Object>'.

Comment: I have solved by use `.subscribe()` instead of `.map`. And It works for me. Thanks you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switchMap operator by rxjs.
You can do it like this:

```
this.http.post(url, param, options).pipe(
  switchMap(data => {
    this.another(); //where data is the response from your http post request
  })
);
```

Comment: I have tried but I canb't able to use it. I got red line with error.

Comment: Actually it shows , `switchMap` is void and you are passing one argument . This is the error.